# What is the ISR for the comparator change interrupt on a dsPIC33F?

Tags: pic, interrupts

I'm asking for the ISR name for the comparator interrupt for a dsPIC33F. I've tried _CompInterrupt, _CMInterrupt and _CMPInterrupt. All three bring up warnings about non-existent ISR names. I can't find it anywhere in the datasheets.

Comment: I suspect it's determined by your compiler. What compiler are you using? Try looking in the .h files that come with the compiler.

Comment: I'm using MPLAB C30, and I've checked the .h file already. I think it's part of the linker, so not included in .h files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this might be what you want http://www.microchip.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=427159&mpage=1&print=true.

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could +10 you. _CMPInterrupt is what I'm looking for. I was calling it __CMPinterrupt, note the extra underscore and case difference.

Comment: It's an old answer and while the link still seems to be alive at the moment it might be worth adding extra details in case the link dies in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet should give a table of interrupt vectors. For the dsPIC33FJ06GS101 it's on page 99, and shows the analogue comparator interrupt (CMP1) at Vector Number 26.

Questions about Microchip devices will probably get a better response on the [Microchip forums](http://www.microchip.com/forums/Default.aspx?).

Comment: I'll link you to Meta where I received approval, albeit not from a moderator. This is still electronics and the Microchip forums are so slow, it takes days to get a response.

Comment: There are forums all over the net for Microchip devices, AVRs, your LPC2000 group, etc.   E&R is a place for asking and answering questions about Microchip devices as well as others.  It's ironic, though, that the answer to this question was a link to a forum....

Answer (score 0):

For me (DSPIC33E and XC16 compiler) _CM1Interrupt works!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the names of interrupts in linker file of MCU, as an examples if you use dspic33ep512MU810, linker file is p33ep512mu810.gld and it is located in compiler folder. If you edit the file you can see all interrupts vector names which are defined.